# Deleted my git folder accidentally. How to connect local copy to repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and made a very silly mistake.

I was working on a project and was pushing my code to gitlab and everything was fine. But then I accidentally deleted my project. I panicked. Downloaded the project from gitlab and imported it in Intellij. I did not connect this "local downloaded copy" to my remote repo.

Now, I want to push the changes I did locally to my repo. Since I am new to this, I am not sure how to push only the changes to my repo and not the entire thing again.

Comment: You should 'clone' and not download. I wonder if it gets you the repo as a git repo if you download.

Comment: No it doesn't. Thats why I am stuck now. I want to only push the changes to repo and not the whole thing again. What should I do? @vivek_23

Comment: You clone the current repo to your local machine. You add all the changes you made locally. Then, you will be able to only push the changes.

Answer (score 0):

open a new folder  open command line there

```
 git init

git clone git@github.com:yourrepo
```

then open code then make your changes locally. After finish your optimize in code

```
git commit -m "Your message"

git push -u origin master
```

If u are using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code u can push with them easier